# How can I connect to remote Tomcat server behind NAT from another IP?

Tags: tomcat, portforwarding, nat

I want to use my idle machine as a tomcat server, which runs on Ubuntu.

Currently, the idle machine is behind a NAT, and the external port (say 234) to the machine has already been set in the router. On my PC, I usually connect to the machine using ssh like "1.2.3.4 -p 234", and I can ping the machine with "telnet 1.2.3.4 234" in CMD. But how can I furthur connect to the internal Tomcat with port 8080 on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I port-forwarded external port 234 to 8080. Now I can see tomcat homepage with 1.2.3.4:234.

But the new problem is, I can no longer connect to the machine itself with "ssh 1.2.3.4 -p 234", can I get both things done?